# subprocess call not getting full conda env

Tags: bash, docker, anaconda, conda

I am trying to get my conda env through a subprocess call inside an Ipython shell but not getting the `defaults` packages:

```
(pnlpipe3) [root@ddcf83835bcf logs-2021-01-20]# ipython
Python 3.6.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec  9 2020, 00:36:02)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from subprocess import check_output

In [2]: check_output('conda env export', shell=True)
Out[2]: b'name: pnlpipe3\nchannels:\n  - defaults\nprefix: /home/pnlbwh/miniconda3/envs/pnlpipe3/envs/pnlpipe3\n'
```

However, if I make the call in a bash shell natively, I get the full list:

```
(pnlpipe3) [root@ddcf83835bcf logs-2021-01-20]# conda env export
name: pnlpipe3
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
 - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
 - _tflow_select=2.3.0=mkl
 - absl-py=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
 - agate=1.6.1=py36_2
 - agate-dbf=0.2.2=py_0
 - agate-excel=0.2.3=py_0
 - agate-sql=0.5.5=py_0
 - astor=0.8.1=py36_0
 - babel=2.9.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
prefix: /home/pnlbwh/miniconda3/envs/pnlpipe3
```

Can anyone explain this discrepancy and tell how to make it right for the Ipython shell?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  What is your OS and conda version?

Comment: CentOS 7 and conda 4.6.14

Comment: Also happening with conda 4.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after investigating for a while, I seem to have found the solution. The problem happens with my environment conda but not with the base conda. `CONDA_EXE` is my base conda which finds the list fine:

```
(pnlpipe3) [root@ddcf83835bcf logs-2021-01-20]# env | grep CONDA
CONDA_SHLVL=2
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(pnlpipe3)
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP=
CONDA_EXE=/home/pnlbwh/miniconda3/bin/conda
_CE_CONDA=
CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/pnlbwh/miniconda3
CONDA_PREFIX=/home/pnlbwh/miniconda3/envs/pnlpipe3
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/pnlbwh/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=pnlpipe3
```

But my subprocess call uses the environment conda `/home/pnlbwh/miniconda3/envs/pnlpipe3/bin/conda` which cannot find the list.

That said, I did:

> check_output(f"{environ['CONDA_EXE']} env export", shell=True)

to solve this issue.